# WSO2 Response Binary while calling endpoint

Tags: binary, wso2, decode, endpoint

Currently I am calling endpoint called

http://leshan.eclipse.org/api/clients

If I call this endpoint in Postman and Browser It gives Proper json response 
On the other hand If I use in WSO2 using log mediator shows binary response

```
{"binary":"PCFET0NUWVBFIEhUTUwgUFVCTElDICItLy9JRVRGLy9EVEQgSFRNTCAyLjAvL0VOIj4KPGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+Cjx0aXRsZT4zMDEgTW92ZWQgUGVybWFuZW50bHk8L3RpdGxlPgo8L2hlYWQ+PGJvZHk+CjxoMT5Nb3ZlZCBQZXJtYW5lbnRseTwvaDE+CjxwPlRoZSBkb2N1bWVudCBoYXMgbW92ZWQgPGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cHM6Ly9sZXNoYW4uZWNsaXBzZS5vcmcvYXBpL2NsaWVudHMiPmhlcmU8L2E+LjwvcD4KPGhyPgo8YWRkcmVzcz5BcGFjaGUvMi40LjI1IChEZWJpYW4pIFNlcnZlciBhdCBsZXNoYW4uZWNsaXBzZS5vcmcgUG9ydCA4MDwvYWRkcmVzcz4KPC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4K"}
```

If I decode this it gives text/html response by saying document has been moved permenantly to https://leshan.eclipse.org/api/clients   301 status code
 and I have already configure the axis2.xml file for specific response

Suggestion needed to how can I get response in Json Or Xml Format

Comment: Which WSO2 product and version you are using?

Comment: WSO2 Enterprise integrator 6.0

Comment: Can you show the sequence where you  make the call from wso2?

Comment: <inSequence>
            <iterate expression="/">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="get" uri-template="http://leshan.eclipse.org/api/clients"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </iterate>   <log>
                <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="Response"/>
            </log>